# Convert an array of arrays into a matrix

Tags: numpy

In my application, it makes a lot of sense to carry around matrices of matrices.  Because numpy doesn't like it, and because working with arrays is most of the times lighter, I ended up with arrays of arrays.  I am quite happy with them.

It looks like that:

```
    [ [S11hh S11hv] [S12hh S12hv] ]
    [ [S11vh S11vv] [S12vh S12vv] ]
S = [                             ]
    [ [S21hh S21hv] [S22hh S22hv] ]
    [ [S21vh S21vv] [S22vh S22vv] ]
```

(This is for coefficients of reflection and transmission in horizontal and vertical polarizations, it's optics.)

However, at some point in my code I need to do a matrix multiplication using all of S, instead of only parts of it:

```
M = S.dot(L)
```

where L looks like:

```
    [ [L1hh L1hv] ]
    [ [L1vh L1vv] ]
L = [             ]
    [ [L2hh L2hv] ]
    [ [L2vh L2vv] ]
```

If I naively run

```
M = S.dot(L)
```

I end up with something in 6 dimensions which is not what I want.  Actually I expect the result to be exactly similar to what would happen if my arrays of arrays were just matrices :

```
    [ S11hh S11hv S12hh S12hv ]
    [ S11vh S11vv S12vh S12vv ]
S = [ S21hh S21hv S22hh S22hv ]
    [ S21vh S21vv S22vh S22vv ]

    [ L1hh L1hv ]
    [ L1vh L1vv ]
L = [ L2hh L2hv ]
    [ L2vh L2vv ]
```

Then I would re-group the elements 4 by 4.

What is an elegant numpyic way of making matrices out of these arrays ?  I tried bmat, but bmat isn't happy with what I have; it works well with a list of list of matrices, but not with a 4D array, for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is a trick about transposition (the transpose of a matrix or matrix is NOT the transpose of the big equivalent matrix), and since bmat frowns upon the original data structure, I came up with that code:

```
def ArrayOfArrayToMatrix(a, transpose=False):
    """
    >>> a1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
    >>> a2 = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
    >>> a3 = np.array([[9, 10], [11, 12]])
    >>> a4 = np.array([[13, 14], [15, 16]])

    With 4D arrays (matrix of matrices):

    >>> a = np.array([[a1, a2], [a3, a4]])
    >>> print ArrayOfArrayToMatrix(a)
    [[ 1  2  5  6]
     [ 3  4  7  8]
     [ 9 10 13 14]
     [11 12 15 16]]
    >>> a = np.array([[a1, a2]])
    >>> print ArrayOfArrayToMatrix(a)
    [[ 1  2  5  6]
     [ 3  4  7  8]]
    >>> print ArrayOfArrayToMatrix(a, True)
    [[ 1  2]
     [ 3  4]
     [ 5  6]
     [ 7  8]]

    With 3D arrays (vector of matrices): 

    >>> a = np.array([a1, a2])
    >>> print ArrayOfArrayToMatrix(a)
    [[ 1  2  5  6]
     [ 3  4  7  8]]
    >>> print ArrayOfArrayToMatrix(a, True)
    [[ 1  2]
     [ 3  4]
     [ 5  6]
     [ 7  8]]

    """
    # bmat doesn't like arrays so we feed it python lists.
    dim = len(a.shape)
    if dim == 3:
        if transpose:
            lst = [elem.T for elem in a]
        else:
            lst = [elem for elem in a]
    elif dim == 4:
        if transpose:
            lst = [[elem.T for elem in row] for row in a]
        else:
            lst = [[elem for elem in row] for row in a]
    else:
        raise TypeError("Only accepts 3D or 4D arrays.")
    mat = np.bmat(lst)
    if transpose:
        mat = mat.T
    return mat
```

Am I reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

You can create *one* big matrix instead of the array of arrays (you can use `bmat` for that). This will enable the big dot product. Then you can reference each sub-matrix with a sliced view.

Comment: That was the way I wrote my code first, and I walked away from that once I realized it forced me to slice and transpose all over the place. Only in one place I do need a matrix.  And as I said, bmat doesn't work out of the box for this task.